# how to re trigger the the ETL packages when it fails?

Tags: sql-server

I have a parent package. In that I am renaming the source files. this package failing due to the duplicate files in the source folder and I already have a package to  remove duplicate files. but my problem is how to re trigger the main package when it fails due to the duplicate files without manual work?

Comment: Are you needing to do any checks before package restart such as checking for this specific error and then triggering a restart, or, do you want it to try and continue regardless of errors? 

Surely your package that removes duplicate files should execute before your main package to avoid this scenario?

Comment: thanks  Jonathon Ogden, before renaming the files i can execute my package. this is one solution. I am looking for another solution.

Comment: can i use checkpoints?, In event handler can I use execute package task?

Comment: Are you using SSIS ? If you are and if you use agent jobs. You can run the "remove duplicate files" package if the main package fails and then run the main package again

Comment: @manjunathk yes, you can use checkpoints. That's usually the go-to method. Or, you can go down the SQL Agent route and even set up Stored Procedures that can trigger packages to run again.

Comment: @Jonathon Ogden, please can you explain more about last option you have mentioned above?